# coredata data fetching increases memory uses ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, memory-leaks

i am using coredata (first time using) for saving large amout of data(images,video paths, html text)
when i am fetching data using prdicate **fetchRequest** NSArray Memory usage increases 10 to 15 mb every time. Sometimes it will cross over 400-500mb..app slow down, but not crashed

i want to know ,is it normally in core database?
is there any method to fetch data without increassing memory usage.?

if not then how can i solve this issue. 
if anyone knows the reason or any idea please share.

[image: memory usage image]

My code is shown below

```
-(void)GetDatafromPrimaryKey:(NSString *)PrimaryKeyTxt EntityName:(NSString *)EntityName {

NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:EntityName  inManagedObjectContext: context];
[fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"primaryKey == %@",PrimaryKeyTxt]];
// [fetch setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
[fetch setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:NO];

chatAry = [context  executeFetchRequest:fetch  error:&error];
NSLog(@"---> %lu",(unsigned long)chatAry.count);
if (error != nil) {
    // Deal with failure
}
else {
 }
 }
```

Comment: you should save image and videos in application directory instead of core data and save path url of that image videos in core data... other wise saving large amount of images and videos in core data will consume more memory as it take whole image and video in memory once to save it to core data

Comment: @Sharma sir, i have used DocumentsDirectory before..but result is same. memory increases :(

Comment: using `sqlite` is a recommended way to handle large amount of data inside the app and it is most preferred way also.

Comment: @vaibhav thanks  .. next time i will use sqlite.. but my app is almost complete, i don't want to code again.. :D   .. i have tried with GCD Async also but not getting expected result

Comment: @VarinderSingh, GCD wont helped you anymore in this situation because its a single threaded until and unless you use `sqlite`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to save images into CoreData. You should save them to disk, and perhaps have the path in CoreData. Better yet, you could use NSCache if that image will change.

If you deal with large amounts of data, use:

```
[fetch setLimit:20];
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit?language=objc

You will most likely display a maximum of 20 elements on a screen so why fetch all the data when you only need a small amount of it?